# How to write method in Playwright to wait until until item changes the color?

Tags: typescript, playwright

Maybe somebody could help me with my issue with Playwright?
My goal is to write Playwright method that will wait until the icon changes color to #8E8E90.
Unfortunately, it does not work and does not wait until it is done. How can I achieve this?
My code:

```
async checkItemColorChanged() {
await test.step('check', async () => {
  await waitUntil(
    () => this.page.locator('[data-test="test"] >> svg >> path').getAttribute('fill') == '#8E8E90',
    { timeout: 4000 },
  );
});
```

}

Comment: getAttribute is async. You need to await it before the comparison

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I modified my code but still, didn't work:
  
`async checkItemColorChanged() {
    await test.step('check', async () => {
   const color = await this.page.locator('[data-test="test"] >> svg >> path').getAttribute('fill');
      await waitUntil(
        () => this.page.locator(color) == '#8E8E90',
        { timeout: 4000 },
      );
    });
  } `

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
await page.waitForFunction(
  el => el.fill == '#8E8E90',
  this.page.$('[data-test="test"] >> svg >> path'),
  { timeout: 4000 });
```